# Executing Fortran code in Python and Storing Output

Tags: python, python-2.7, fortran

I'm working with executing fortran code (not sure which fortran, I'm not familiar with the language). I execute two codes that require some input (executing using command line). After executing, I open the resulting .dat files and copy and paste values into csv files that I later plot in python. I have to execute these files multiple times for different inputs and it gets very tedious. Is there any way to code in python (2.7) to loop through input values and execute fortran code with them and then read through the resulting .dat files and store them for me? I'm working on a Windows machine, but in order to execute the fortran code I have been using PuTTy and sshing into a linux environment.

Comment: Take a look at `f2py` in the `numpy` module http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/

Comment: Please don't use f2py... It is not maintained any more and limited to old versions of Fortran. Instead, use `ctypes` and `iso-c-bindings` in Fortran.

Comment: Depending on how convoluted your Fortran code is, it may be easier to leave it as it is and use the `subprocess` module in python to start the Fortran program. It is used to execute command line statements: `subprocess.Popen('./a.out')` and you can also interact with the standard input/output/error (if you need to pass command line inputs, for example). It is somewhat of a hack to do it this way though. But the looping through input values is easy and since `subprocess.Popen` blocks (waits) until the program has finished, you can then just treat the output right afterwards in the script.